# Trying to re-use an existing class in lesscss

Tags: css, less, gulp

I would like to create an abstract css class name.

```
//icons.less (from icomoon)
.icon-arrow-down:before {
  content: "\e600";
}

//abstract class name that re-uses existing class name
//compiling lesscss fails at this line
.icon-open-menu:before {
    .icon-arrow-down:before;
}

$ gulp build-less
[17:30:18] Using gulpfile ~/projects/foo/gulpfile.js
[17:30:18] Starting 'build-less'...

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Unrecognised input in file
/Users/user/projects/foo/less/icons.less line no. 138
```

I've done this many times before where I reference an existing class like `.clearfix;` but it doesn't seem to work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to what [Jerreck mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25859632/2680216), you could also use [**`extend`**](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) to achieve *similar* results:

```
.icon-arrow-down:before {
  content: "\e600";
}
.icon-open-menu:before {
  &:extend(.icon-arrow-down:before);
  color: red;
}
```

Output:

```
.icon-arrow-down:before,
.icon-open-menu:before {
  content: "\e600";
}
.icon-open-menu:before {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have isn't just a class, it's a class with a psuedo-selector appended to it.

In LESS, you can append psuedo-selectors to selectors by nesting them inside the selector with this syntax:

```
.icon-arrow-down {
  &:before {
     content: "\e600";
  }
}
```

Then you can reuse your class as a mixin like this:

```
.icon-open-menu {
  .icon-arrow-down;
}
```

This will output:

```
.icon-arrow-down:before {
  content: "\e600";
}
.icon-open-menu:before {
  content: "\e600";
}
```

Comment: This works, but unfortunately, icomoon.io css isn't in LESS format. I was hoping to avoid rewriting. Is there anyway to reuse the initial `.icon-arrow-down:before {}` rule without modifying it?